# Insert the custom array to CoreData using NSBatchInsertRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have my Custom Array which conforms to my CoreData Entity Model. Objective is to insert this to my CoreData table using NSBatchInsertRequest. Issue is My custom Array is not a type of [[String:Any]] which is expecting from the NSBatchInsertRequest objects type. How can I achieve this without looping and converting them to key value pairs (if I loop the objective of NSBatchInsertRequest will be useless). I tried a workaround and got stuck in the middle. What I have done so far i s bellow.

Custom Model

```
struct DataModel:Codable {
  let id:Int?
  let title:String?
  let descriptionText:String?
}
```

Place Im stuck with the error "Cannot convert value of type '[DataModel]' to expected argument type '[[String : Any]]'"

```
func saveData(model: [DataModel]) {

     let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedObjectContext)
    let insertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity:entity!, objects: model)//Error is here

    try! context?.execute(insertRequest)
    try! context?.save()

}
```

What I have tried so far is to try creating an extension to convert it to a dictionary (which I'm not sure if thats the best option)

```
extension Encodable {
 subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
    return dictionary[key]
 }
 var dictionary: [String: Any] {
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSON.encoder.encode(self))) as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
 }
}


struct JSON {
 static let encoder = JSONEncoder()
}
```

But this only converts a single object inside the array (only if you specify the index). Whats the best way to achieve my objective ?

Answer (score 0):

You have already written `var dictionary` in `extension Encodable` to get the dictionary version of your model. You can now map over the array of models inside the `saveData` method.

```
let dictionaries = model.map {$0.dictionary}
```

Comment: I thought about it too but then the issue is it'll again iterate through the array, and that why i made a point that i would lick to know a way that would not iterate the array and convert it. I figured our halfway through and got stuck> imagine u have an array that holds about 1000 records, then your approach would not be useful as it takes times to execute